# How to remove a single selected value from multiple values for the same key from the local storage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Remove a single value from a key having multiple values in the local storage of JavaScript.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).remove();
  localStorage.removeItem();
});

let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') 
                    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) 
                    : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
```

Comment: provide your HTML and a sample localstorage data

Comment: Are you storing an object or an array ?

Comment: I'm using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage stores **strings**. Your code is using JSON to store an array (as a string), which is a common and appropriate way to do it. To remove just one item from the array, you:

1. Get the JSON from local storage
2. Parse the JSON into an array
3. Remove the item from the array
4. Get JSON for the updated array
5. Store that in local storage

Typically I do Steps 1 & 2 on arrival to the page and keep the result. So then I'd do Step 3 on the result I already have and then put it back in storage. You're doing something similar with `itemsArray`, so something along the lines of:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  itemsArray = itemsArray.filter(entry => {
    return /*...code to determine whether to keep `entry`, should
           return true if `entry` isn't for this `li`, false if `entry`
           IS for this `li` */;
  });
  $(this).remove();
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
});
```